# Change the motion hover to click for button on header

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want change the motion hover to click for button on header, but I have no idea how should I do?

https://www.chiepal.jp/

ID revolutionary1108@yahoo.co.jp

PASS password

```
{ this.props.isAuthenticated === true
  ? <div className="header-user">
      <Link to={`/users/edit/${userName}`} className="header-user-btn">
        <p className="setting-btn">設定</p>
      </Link>
      <div className="header-user-dropMenu">
        <ul className="header-user-dropMenu-list">
          <li className="header-user-dropMenu-item"><Link to={`/users/edit/${userName}`}>プロフィールを編集</Link></li>
          <li className="header-user-dropMenu-item"><Link target="_blank" to={`/users/settings`}>アカウント設定</Link></li>
          <li className="header-user-dropMenu-item" onClick={this.handleSignOut}><span>ログアウト</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  : null }
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsCIm.png]

i added new picture.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8c5v.png]

Comment: When you hover over the item Configuration, you get 3 subitems, click it and you go to Edit profile page. Not sure what's the issue?

Comment: thank you for me to reply.

firstly , please login with info below
ID revolutionary1108@yahoo.co.jp 
PASS password

and then, when you cursor the 設定button, the drop menu will appear. but actully I want to not hover to click